# how to join two frames in h2o flow?

Tags: r, h2o

How can i do a join on two frames in h2o flow? I want to join the first column of one frame with the first column a second frame, the second column of one frame with the second column of a second frame and so on.

Comment: read the `?h2o.merge` documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be describing what `h2o.rbind` does. E.g.

```
i1 = as.h2o(iris)
nrow(i1)   #150
i2 = h2o.rbind(i1,i1)
nrow(i2)   #300
```

If you check over on Flow to see what has happened, `getFrames`, you will see "iris" with 150 rows, and "RTMP_sid_abcd_2" (i.e. some random name) with 300 rows. In other words, `h2o.rbind()` creates a new H2O frame.

If by "join" you were thinking an SQL join, where the two frames have a common index column, but otherwise different columns, then you want `h2o.merge()`. (If that was what you wanted, but you cannot get `h2o.merge()` to work, then it would be helpful to see some of your data.)